# Swift Local push notification action view

Tags: swift, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to create a notification with two possible action buttons like "Quick reply" and "Cancel", but I can't find any code examples for this. Please could someone explain how to do this in Swift 3.

Comment: are you trying to with iOS 10?

Comment: yes @SalmanGhumsani

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to give a precise example of what you are looking for. Here's a quick `UNUserNotificationCenter` implementation with an action.

```
import UserNotifications
```

**Define a category ID constant**

```
private let categoryID = "Category"
```

**Setup and register** `UNUserNotificationCenter`

```
// MARK: - Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Configure User Notification Center
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    // Define Actions
    let actionShowSomething = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "ShowSomething", title: "Show Something", options: [])

    // Define Category
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: categoryID, actions: [actionShowSomething], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

    // Register Category
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
}
```

**Example event for triggering the notification**

```
// MARK: - Actions

@IBAction func sheduleNotification(sender: UIButton) {
    // Request Notification Settings
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (notificationSettings) in
        switch notificationSettings.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            self.requestAuthorization(completionHandler: { (success) in
                guard success else { return }

                // Schedule Local Notification
                self.scheduleLocalNotification()
            })
        case .authorized:
            // Schedule Local Notification
            self.scheduleLocalNotification()
        case .denied:
            print("Application Not Allowed to Display Notifications")
        }
    }
}
```

`sheduleNotification` **implementation**

```
// MARK: - Methods

private func scheduleLocalNotification() {
    // Create Notification Content
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    // Configure Notification Content
    notificationContent.title = "Title"
    notificationContent.subtitle = "Subtitle"
    notificationContent.body = "Body"

    // Set Category Identifier
    notificationContent.categoryIdentifier = categoryID

    // Add Trigger
    let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false)

    // Create Notification Request
    let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "cocoacasts_local_notification", content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger)

    // Add Request to User Notification Center
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Unable to Add Notification Request (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
        }
    }
}
```

**Handle user notification authorization**

```
private func requestAuthorization(completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> ()) {
    // Request Authorization
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (success, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Request Authorization Failed (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
        }
        completionHandler(success)
    }
}
```

`UnUserNotificationDelegate` **implementation**

```
extension ViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler 
    completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image: Push example at runtime]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by `UIMutableUserNotificationAction`

for more information look here:-

1) https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/

2) http://www.imore.com/interactive-notifications-ios-8-explained